# Autohotkey (ahk) - Скрипт не меняет язык ввода в некоторых окнах

Tags: autohotkey

есть вот такой, не лучшим образом сделанный скрипт:

```
;--------------------; Keyboard Layout for Language ;--------------------;
 ; For [LAlt]+[LShift] Button key
#IfWinActive
~LAlt & ~LShift::
    SetFormat, Integer, H
    LocaleRussian=0x4090409     ; English Language
    LocaleEnglish=0x4190419     ; Russian Language
    LocaleWinID := WinExist("A")
    ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Int", LocaleWinID, "Int", "0")
    InputLocaleID:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "Int", ThreadID)

    If(InputLocaleID!=LocaleRussian)
    {
        PostMessage, 0x50,, % LocaleRussian,, A
    }
    Else
    {
        If(InputLocaleID!=LocaleEnglish)
            PostMessage, 0x50,, % LocaleEnglish,, A
    }
    Return

 ; For [LShift]+[LAlt] Button key
#IfWinActive
~LShift & ~LAlt::
    SetFormat, Integer, H
    LocaleRussian=0x4090409     ; English Language
    LocaleEnglish=0x4190419     ; Russian Language
    LocaleWinID := WinExist("A")
    ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Int", LocaleWinID, "Int", "0")
    InputLocaleID:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "Int", ThreadID)

    If(InputLocaleID!=LocaleRussian)
    {
        PostMessage, 0x50,, % LocaleRussian,, A
    }
    Else
    {
        If(InputLocaleID!=LocaleEnglish)
            PostMessage, 0x50,, % LocaleEnglish,, A
    }
    Return

 ; For [LControl]+[LAlt] Button key
#IfWinActive
~LControl & ~LAlt::
    LocaleJapan=0x4110411       ; Japan Language
    PostMessage, 0x50,, % LocaleJapan,, A
    Sleep 50
    Send !{CapsLock}        ; Katakana
    Return

 ; For [LAlt]+[LControl] Button key
#IfWinActive
~LAlt & ~LControl::
    LocaleJapan=0x4110411       ; Japan Language
    PostMessage, 0x50,, % LocaleJapan,, A
    Sleep 50
    Send ^{CapsLock}        ; Hiragana
    Return
 ;;;
```

В большинстве приложений скрипт меняет язык ввода, но при выборе активным окна cmd или окна "Найти" в Notepad++ - скрипт язык ввода уже не меняет, хоть окно и находит и проверку языка делает. В целом, это относится также и к любым другим "диалоговым окнам" (к примеру тем, что можно вызвать в браузере, нажав "Сохранить как")

Проблема, как мне видится, связана с ***PostMessage***. Как эту проблему исправить я не знаю, особого опыта работы с ahk нет, про вики знаю, но и там не получилось разобраться в проблеме. На тематическом форуме ответа жду уже больше недели. Надеюсь на хотя бы вашу помощь;

**P.S.** Дополнительными, не столь важным вопросами-

**1)** Можно ли при смене языка ввода сразу указать способов ввода? Чтобы не ставить Хирагану или Катакану через комбинации клавиш, а обойтись чем-то на уровне ***PostMessage***?

**2)** Можно ли объединить ***~LAlt & ~LShift*** и ***~LShift & ~LAlt*** в одну комбинацию? Их пришлось продублировать со сменной порядка, потому что этот самый порядок нажатия клавишь для их исполнения важен.

Спасибо за ваше время

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это подойдет?

`SendMessage, 0x50,, 0x4190419,, A ; меняет язык на русский`

Answer (score 0):

***SendMessage*** влияет, как я понимаю, только на очерёдность обработки запроса. Проблема при использовании ***SendMessage*** вместо ***PostMessage*** не решается

Answer (score 0):

Я смог решить только так, но при этом в играх на секунд лагает:

```
Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста смысл этой фразы: _на секунд лагает_ .